# While executing passport.authenticate, displays as unauthorized 404 in get post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

File `router.js` contains the routers that are used.

In the ionic2, providers are made with the `post` method by giving uri as `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login` which gives `400` bad request error in the debugger tools.

I have found that `when I remove`requireLogin`then the post is working fine.But I need`requireLogin` for authenticating the local login of passport.

**`router.js`**

```
//require the passport strategy from the folder in the project.
  var passport = require('passport');
  var x = require('./usefile/file');

var requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local',{session: false});

module.exports = function(app){

var auth = express.Router();

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

auth.post('/login', requireLogin, function(req, res){
     x.login(req, res)});
}
```

**passport.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var config = require('./auth');
var User = require('../models/user');

var localOptions = {
    usernameField: 'email',
};

var localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function (email, password, done) {
    User.find(
        { email: email }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { error: 'Login failed,Please try again.' });
            }
            if (!isMatch) {
                return done(null, false, { error: 'Login failed, Please try again.' });
            }
            user.comparePassword(function(password, isMatch){
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(!isMatch){
                    return done(null, false, {error:'Login failed, Please try again.'});
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
});
passport.use(localLogin);
```

***Note***: My code is not using the requireLogin which is used to authenticate from the passport, So it is showing 400 bad request error.

Please Help.

Comment: @robertklep if you can help....

Answer (score 0):

have you required your local passport file? You seem to be requiring the npm passport module, and not your local file.

You should change the first line of code in `router.js` to

```js
//require the passport strategy from the folder in the project.
var passport = require('./passport');//<--change this line
var x = require('./usefile/file');

var requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local',{session: false});

module.exports = function(app){

var auth = express.Router();

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

auth.post('/login', requireLogin, function(req, res){
     x.login(req, res)});
}
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: yes, I have already required the local passport file as I have mentioned in the first line of the comment in `router.js`

Comment: and I pointed to you that what you required in `router.js` is not your local file, but the npm module. for it to be local, you need to precede it with `./`; understood?

Comment: it is displaying `error: cannot find module' ./passport'`

Comment: pls point it to wherever you have your `passport.js` file saved.

Comment: Actually,my server is hitting the endpoint, but this line in `router.js` `auth.post('/login', requireLogin, function(req, res){
     x.login(req, res)});
}`  in this `requireLogin` is having some problem, as it is used to authenticate the local passport.

Comment: where do you have passport.js in your project? just require the file from there. e.g. `require('/path/to/passport.js')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144356/discussion-between-kennasoft-and-aditya-jain).